# how do i load thousands of rows in my asp.net mvc project from database into slickgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

All the examples except for the Ajax example creates random values with javascript.  What is the standard way to load from database?  I don't necessarily need to load using Ajax but i don't think i want to generate each value and write it out in the html or is that how it has to be done?

Comment: What examples? What code? if you really want an answer, elaborate your question and take some time to write it out as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use ajax, you have to write every value on the html. No other way.
Using pagination helps easing the load.